# What type to mechanical joint to achive Slide then Rotation motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms

I have two parts (Green and red fixed) i want to connect them with a joint (Blue) that permit the green one to slide outwards then rotate.

**Side View** **(Right part)**
[image: Pieces position]

[image: Top View]

a simple pivot point doesn't work since the  two piece will collide with each other.

I thought about using 4-bars linkage, but couldn't figure out the right combination to give the path of motion I'm looking for
[image]

Comment: Check out hinges used for things like kitchen cupboards.

Comment: Check out MotionGen (on app stores) it allows you to specify positions, and calculates the required linkages to satisfy those

Comment: By the way "a simple pivoting motion" will work, if the pivot is about the bottom right corner of the red block. No need for this two-stage malarkey? Or do they need to end up coplanar? What is the full list of constraints?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift The green part is L shaped and there one on each side, they will collide with a simple rotation. 
Another constraint is the necessity to have the joint on the inside, can't alter or modify the outside.
I edited the post and added top view.